# Ensure ALL iPhone burst shoot images are shared via upload for Selection & Editing? How?

Tags: photo-editing, iphone, editing, photo-shoot, creative-cloud

Ensure ALL iPhone burst shoot images are shared via upload for Selection & Editing? How?

- We did a casual photo shoot, lots of burst shots a few months back.

  - We never got around to working on the pictures together nor did he get to them off his iPhone.
- I know it’s possible for him to upload the pics to a cloud drive/ folder such as Dropbox/ google drive / onedrive/ pcloud. I use them a lot for non photography files.
- **The issue now is there's something about Burst mode that all images from that burst sequence are not uploaded or shared. How do we make this happen?**

I wonder if there’s a better way for him to upload & share with me while we can work on it online itself?

- Without me having to download all of them for working on them on my iPhone or Windows based Surface Pro.

We might need to do a repeat of this in the future & again work remotely from each other.

**Is there a better photo selection & editing workflow here?**

Ps: I am a tech geek but not regular with such shoot & workflows.

Comment: Why the negative? This iPhone thing is a legit PIA. The only way we got a copy of these pics out was uploading to pCloud via its app. All others mentioned above did not work

Answer (score 0):

So this is part of the answer that may help someone and hopefully we can update it with more testing.

This iPhone thing is a legit PIA.

- The only way we got a copy of these pics out was uploading to pCloud via its app.
- All others mentioned above did not work to give us the Burst shots:

  - DropBox, GDrive, OneDrive, Box

Now, how to share and do selection, editing? We've shared a folder between each other, and trying to figure out what would make an easy repeatable workflow that allows easy Browsing, Selection and Editing